# show that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}(1-a_{k})<\frac{2}{3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Let $a_{1}=\dfrac{1}{2}$, and such $a_{n+1}=a_{n}-a_{n}\ln{a_{n}}$,show that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(1-a_{k})<\dfrac{2}{3}$$

My attemp: let $1-a_{n}=b_{n}$,then we have
$$b_{n+1}=b_{n}+(1-b_{n})\ln{(1-b_{n})}<b^2_{n}<\cdots<(b_{1})^{2^{n}}=\dfrac{1}{2^{2^n}}$$
where use $\ln{(1+x)}<x,x>-1$
so
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(1-a_{k})<\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{2^{2^{k-1}}}?$$

But $$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{1}{2^{2^{k-1}}}=0.816\cdots$$big than$\frac{2}{3}$,so this inequality How to prove it?

Comment: I think it's sadism.

Comment: Why don't you separate the sum: $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\, \left(1-a_k\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n\,\left(1-a_k\right)+\sum_{k={n+1}}^\infty\,\left(1-a_k\right)\,?$$  Pick a good $n$ and use your estimate for $\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \,\left(1-a_k\right)$.

Comment: It's easy to see that the sequence $a_k$ in the question corresponds with a (fast converging) Newton-Raphson method for calculating numerically the zero at $x=1$ of the function $\,f(x) = \ln(x)$ :
$$
a_{n+1} = a_n - \frac{f(a_n)}{f'(a_n)} = a_n - \frac{\ln(a_n)}{1/a_n}
$$
Then someone smarter than me might find the [Wikipedia reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) helpful to formulate a decent answer.

Comment: One formula in the abovementioned [Wikipedia reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) leads to:
$$
1-a_{n+1} \approx -\frac{f''(1)}{2f'(1)}(1-a_n)^2 = (1-a_n)^2/2
$$
Giving rise to a sharper estimate than the $0.816\cdots$ in the question.

Comment: Maybe it could help your equality/condition is equivalent to : $$e^{W(\frac{a_{n+1}}{-e})+1}=a_n$$ where W(x) is the Lambert function .

Answer (score 0):

As used by the OP: $\enspace b_n:=1-a_n$

Examples: $\enspace\displaystyle b_1=0.5\enspace , \enspace b_2=0.5-0.5\ln 2\enspace , \enspace b_3 = b_2 + (1-b_2) \ln (1-b_2) <0.013$

We have: $\enspace b_n<-\ln(1-b_n)\enspace$ => $\enspace a_{n+1}=a_n(1-\ln a_n)>a_n(1+b_n)\enspace$ => $\enspace b_{n+1}<b_n^2\enspace$

Using $\,b_{n+1}<b_n^2\,$ we begin with $\,b_4=1-a_4<0.0001=0.1^{2^2}\,$ and get 
$\enspace b_n<0.1^{2^{n-2}}\,$ .

It follows:

$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=1}^n (1-a_k) < b_1 + b_2 + b_3 + \sum\limits_{k=4}^\infty 0.1^{2^{k-2}}$

$\displaystyle < 1- 0.5 \ln 2 + 0.013 + \sum\limits_{k=4}^5 0.1^{2^{k-2}} + \sum\limits_{k=4}^\infty 0.1^{12+k} $

$\displaystyle = 1- 0.5 \ln 2 + 0.013 + 0.00010001 + \frac{1}{9}0.1^{15} $

$\displaystyle < 1- 0.5 \ln 2 + 0.013 + 0.00010002 < 0,66652643 <\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: good insight, still not nice and simple...

Comment: the last sum how to get the value $0.00010001$

Comment: @geromty : I think with $\,\sum\limits_{k=4}^\infty 0.1^{2^{k-2}} < 0.00010002\,$ it becomes clear. :-)

Comment: @geromty : $\enspace\displaystyle 0.00010001=\sum\limits_{v=2}^3 0.1^{2^v} $

Comment: @lion : Now it's nice and simple. :-)

Comment: @geromty :  Is there any uncertainty or question left ?

Answer (score 0):

We can prove that $0< a_{n}< 1$ inductively by making use of the graph$:\quad y= x\left ( 1- \ln x \right ).$ We let
$$b_{n}:= 1- a_{n}, \left \{ b_{n} \right \}_{n= 1}^{\infty}\Leftrightarrow b_{1}= \frac{1}{2}, b_{n+ 1}= b_{n}+ \left ( 1- b_{n} \right )\ln\left ( 1- b_{n} \right )$$
Well$,\quad a_{n+ 1}- a_{n}= -a_{n}\ln n> 0,$ then $b_{n+ 1}< b_{n}\Rightarrow 0< b_{n}< b_{1}= \frac{1}{2},$ according to inequality
$$\ln\left ( 1- x \right )< -x,\quad x\in\left ( 0, 1 \right )$$
So$,\quad n> 2$
$$\Rightarrow b_{n}= b_{n- 1}+ \left ( 1- b_{n- 1} \right )\ln\left ( 1- b_{n- 1} \right )< b_{n- 1}- \left ( 1- b_{n- 1} \right )b_{n- 1}= b_{n- 1}^{2}\Rightarrow b_{n}< b_{2}^{2^{n- 2}}=$$
$$= \left ( \frac{1- \ln 2}{2} \right )^{2^{n- 2}}\Rightarrow\sum_{k= 1}^{n}b_{k}< \sum_{k= 1}^{n}\left ( \frac{1- \ln 2}{2} \right )^{2^{k- 2}}< \sum_{k= 1}^{\infty}\left ( \frac{1- \ln 2}{2} \right )^{2^{k- 2}}= 0.56\cdots< \frac{2}{3}$$

Answer (score -2):

You can add more coefficients in the Taylor expansion
$$\log(1-x)\leq-x-x^2/2+...$$ 
in order to obtain the sharper bound
$$b_{n}+(1-b_{n})\ln{(1-b_{n})}<b^2_{n}/2+b_n^3/2$$
and so on, if it is necessary.

Comment: Then How to prove this inequality?

Comment: @geromty: by Taylor series, for instance. The LHS is a primitive of $-\log(1-x)$ evaluated at $b_n$, and the Taylor series of $-\log(1-x)$ only has positive coefficients.

Comment: The bound is really sharp, however, since $$\sum_{k\geq 1}(1-a_k)\approx 0.665926577$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio,can you post your solution?

Comment: @geromty: I do not have an elegant solution at the moment. I just computed $(1-a_k)$ up to twelve figures for any $k\in[1,5]$, then exploited the shown bound for $\sum_{k\geq 6}(1-a_k)$.

Comment: oh,It is said this sequality have simple and nice methods,.but I ..